# problem in loading media files into templates

Tags: django, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-media

My django project is searching for images in
`/profile/<pk>/myapp/profile_pics/images.jpg`
instead of `myapp/profile_pics/images.jpg`

similar to this question [image isn't uploaded to media root using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427649/image-isnt-uploaded-to-media-root-using-django)

`settings.py` -

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

`urls.py` -

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`views.py`-

```
def profile(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html',{'account': user})
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Could you add more information? You saw their question which has tons of details.
What have you done for your ```settings.py``` in terms of your ```MEDIA_ROOT``` and ```MEDIA_URL``` ?

Comment: plz post your `urls.py` and `settings.py`

Comment: @Jonas @edwin-cruz added `urls.py`, `views.py` and `settings.py`

Comment: well you just want to get he user image. You can get it with the help of user object related in your profile model.

Comment: @Suraj please add your template as well, so I can look into your issue